# What does TP-Link port VLAN actually do at low level?

Tags: networking, switch

First of all, I already know there are 2 types of VLAN:

1. Port based VLAN
2. Tag based VLAN (aka IEEE 802.1q)

I am using a TP-Link TL-R480T+ v6. The manual states that its **switch** uses port VLAN - I am fine with that.

> **4.3.5.6 Port VLAN**
>
> The VLAN function can prevent the broadcast storm in LANs and enhance
>   the network security. By creating VLANs in a physical LAN, you can
>   divide the LAN into multiple logical LANs, each of which has a
>   broadcast domain of its own. Hosts in the same VLAN communicate with
>   one another as if they are in a LAN. However, hosts in different VLANs
>   cannot communicate with one another directly. Therefore, broadcast
>   packets are limited in a VLAN.
>
> TL-R480T+ provides the Port VLAN function, which allows you to create
>   multiple logical VLANs for the LAN ports based on their port numbers.

Here is how it looks like on the web interface:

[image]

It does indeed prevent hosts from different VLAN from communicating with each other. But the first strange thing I found after configuring 3 different VLANs is that: the **router**'s interface that connects to the **switch** uses a single IP address `192.168.0.1` for all VLANs. A host from any VLAN is able to connect to the router using that address. How can it even happen?

I assumed that internally its router created 3 different virtual interfaces facing 3 VLANs, with same IP address `192.168.0.1` for all 3 interfaces (sounds too stupid to be true). But then, I just realized that the integrated **DHCP server** also connected to all VLANs and handed out **non-duplicate** addresses to clients belonging to different VLANs. Why did it have do that?

I decided to use 2 computers connected to 2 different ports (or VLANs), and configured them to use the same IP address. Guess what? One of them did not work due to IP conflict. Since when are hosts from different broadcast domains unable to use the same IP address?

Can someone guess how this thing work under the hood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very much like the *port isolation* (aka "private VLAN") feature found in many switches.

Ignore "VLAN" in its name. It is actually meant to work like a normal single subnet (single broadcast domain), except all of the 'client' or 'untrusted' ports can *only* send/receive Ethernet frames to the 'router' or 'trusted' port – but not directly between each other.

(Or in other words: From the router's perspective, all clients are in a single broadcast domain, nothing has changed from regular Ethernet. The router still resolves IP addresses the same way, whether duplicate or not. Only from the clients' perspective, because the client is only allowed to send frames to the router, the result is as if each client had a separate virtual broadcast domain from everyone else. Thus TP-Link's description is not wrong, just incomplete.)

For example, if you have a public network full of mutually untrusted devices – like a dorm LAN or coffee shop Wi-Fi – you want the clients to only have Internet access but not be able to contact each other. (Wi-Fi APs have the same feature, but call it "client isolation.")

This saves you from creating a massive number of tiny VLANs, IP subnets, and DHCP pools, each holding just one client device (and each IP address being bound to one physical port due to VLANs usually being assigned statically).

Port isolation is sometimes used together with Proxy-ARP, where the router replies to ARP requests on behalf of the entire LAN. This would allow clients to reach each other again, but only through the router – which allows the packets to be filtered using the router's firewall rules, similarly to cross-VLAN traffic.